# How to parse an inner field in a nested JSON object

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON object similar to this one:

```
{
  "name": "Cain",
  "parents": {
    "mother" : "Eve",
    "father" : "Adam"
  }
}
```

Now I want to parse "name" and "mother" into this struct:

```
struct {
  Name String
  Mother String `json:"???"`
}
```

I want to specify the JSON field name with the `json:...` struct tag, however I don't know what to use as tag, because it is not the top object I am interested in. I found nothing about this in the [`encoding/json`](http://blog.golang.org/2011/01/json-and-go.html) package docs nor in the popular blog post [JSON and Go](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/). I also tested `mother`, `parents/mother` and `parents.mother`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike `encoding/xml`, the `json` package doesn't provide a way to access nested values. You'll want to either create a separate Parents struct or assign the type to be `map[string]string`. For example:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Parents map[string]string
}
```

You could then provide a getter for mother as so:

```
func (p *Person) Mother() string {
    return p.Parents["mother"]
}
```

This may or may not play into your current codebase and if refactoring the `Mother` field to a method call is not on the menu, then you may want to create a separate method for decoding and conforming to your current struct.

Answer (score 20):

You could use structs so long as your incoming data isn't too dynamic.

http://play.golang.org/p/bUZ8l6WgvL

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    )

type User struct {
    Name string
    Parents struct {
        Mother string
        Father string
    }
}

func main() {
    encoded := `{
        "name": "Cain",
        "parents": {
            "mother": "Eve",
            "father": "Adam"
        }
    }`

    // Decode the json object
    u := &User{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(encoded), &u)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Print out mother and father
    fmt.Printf("Mother: %s\n", u.Parents.Mother)
    fmt.Printf("Father: %s\n", u.Parents.Father)
}
```

Comment: I am also aware of this. However I don't want to use two structs but one, and don't want to nest them. Struct field tags give a way to specify which JSON field should be used, but I was curious if they give a way to access nested fields, fields that are not members of the root object.

Comment: `remy_o` said on `#go-nuts`, that the `encoding/json` package does not do what i asked for, so this is the answer I'm stuck with. Or in his words: "the json package is not XPath".

Answer (score 6):

Here's some code I baked up real quick in the Go Playground

http://play.golang.org/p/PiWwpUbBqt

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    )

func main() {
    encoded := `{
        "name": "Cain",
        "parents": {
            "mother": "Eve"
            "father": "Adam"
        }
    }`

    // Decode the json object
    var j map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(encoded), &j)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // pull out the parents object
    parents := j["parents"].(map[string]interface{})

    // Print out mother and father
    fmt.Printf("Mother: %s\n", parents["mother"].(string))
    fmt.Printf("Father: %s\n", parents["father"].(string))
}
```

There might be a better way.  I'm looking forward to seeing the other answers. :-)

Comment: I know this works, but I hope there is a more... readable solution.

Comment: It has to work this way because interface{} must be asserted to be a type (in this case, type map[string]interface{}). The simpler way is to use a lib with helper methods such as [go-simplejson](http://godoc.org/github.com/bitly/go-simplejson)

Comment: this unmarshalling a nested struct is giving me serious headaches. boooo

Answer (score 5):

More recently, [gjson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson) supports selection of nested JSON properties.

```
name := gjson.Get(json, "name")
mother := gjson.Get(json, "parents.mother")
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using an intermediary struct as the one suggested above for parsing, and then putting the relevant values in your "real" struct?

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    )

type MyObject struct{
  Name string
  Mother string
}

type MyParseObj struct{
   Name string
   Parents struct {
         Mother string
         Father string
   } 
}


func main() {
    encoded := `{
         "name": "Cain",
         "parents": {
             "mother": "Eve",
             "father": "Adam"
         }
    }`

    pj := &MyParseObj{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(encoded), pj); err != nil {
        return
    }
    final := &MyObject{Name: pj.Name, Mother: pj.Parents.Mother}
    fmt.Println(final)  
}
```